AADB2C90238 provided token does not contain valid issuer (B2C openidconnect)
I am stuck with the OpenIdConnect. I am trying to change the sign in method from personal (login.live.com) to work account (login.microsoftonline.com). The login with login.live.com is working perfectly so I thought it would just be to change the providername and metadata to login.microsoftonline.com. But it wasn't so easy, I am getting "AADB2C90238 provided token does not contain valid issuer" when I try to login with my business account.
Here is part of the working custom policy where it works to login with a Microsoft account (which means the app registration, clientid etc is correct):

And this is what I am trying to change to trying to make it possible to instead sign in with a business/work account:

I've tried to replace the providername and metadata to login.microsoftonline.com

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#claims

The error "AADB2C90238 provided token does not contain valid issuer" usually occurs if you are passing invalid issuer to validate the token.
To resolve the error and to validate access token for Work account you must pass issuer as https://sts.windows.net/ or  https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/TenantID/v2.0/ based on your requirement . Refer this MsDoc

The security token service (STS) that creates and provides the token is identified, along with the directory where the user was authenticated.
Your application must verify the issuer claim to ensure the token originated from the correct endpoint.
Validating the issuer claim ensures the token's source is trusted.

IssuanceClaimPattern must be AuthorityAndTenantGuid or AuthorityWithTfp check this MsDoc
Try to modify the XML file like below:
<TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="OIDC">
    <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
      <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
      <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
      <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
      <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
      <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
      <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
      <Item Key="client_id">YOUR_CLIENT_ID</Item>
      <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">43200</Item>
      <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">43200</Item>
      <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">864000</Item>
      <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">864000</Item>
      <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>

OR if you are making use of Azure AD B2C user flow to sign in then use the below:
<TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="OIDC">
        <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
        <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.microsoftonline.com</Item>
            <!-- Microsoft Online -->
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://Tenant.b2clogin.com/TenantID/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_SUSI</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="Use Policy InRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id"></Item>
            <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">43200</Item>
            <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">43200</Item>
            <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">864000</Item>
            <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">864000</Item>
            <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDS below for e -->
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://TenantName.b2clogin.com/TenantID/v2.0/</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
            <!-- Cryptographic keys section -->
            <!-- Add keys here -->
        </CryptographicKeys>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>


